# Can't view the selecteditems in listview

Tags: c#

I can't view the `selecteditems` into the `listview`. What is the problem with this code?

```
private void ListView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0) {
        this.TextBox1.Text = this.ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text;
        this.TextBox2.Text = this.ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text;
        this.TextBox3.Text = this.ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(2).Text;
        this.TextBox4.Text = this.ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(3).Text;
        this.TextBox5.Text = this.ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(4).Text;
        this.TextBox6.Text = this.ListView1.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(5).Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you need `SelectedItems[0]` instead of `SelectedItems(0)`?

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be (at least) two problems,

Firstly, you should address your indexer by square bracket `[]` instead of parentheses `()` (parentheses for indexing is used in VB.Net, not C#):

```
this.TextBox1.Text = this.ListView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;
```

Secondly, the `subitems` index should start from `0` instead of `1`:

```
private void ListView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
        if (this.ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0) {
                this.TextBox1.Text = this.ListView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;
                this.TextBox2.Text = this.ListView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text; //zero here
                this.TextBox3.Text = this.ListView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
                this.TextBox4.Text = this.ListView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text;
                this.TextBox5.Text = this.ListView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text;
                this.TextBox6.Text = this.ListView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[4].Text;
        }

}
```